# Placing variable in curl request under option -F

Tags: bash, curl

I am looking a way to use variable inside **"file=@/my/file/path/from/variable/tshootinginfo.txt"** in a bash shell on Debian 9.3.

My CURL request:

```
curl -s -k -D- -u ${user}:${password} -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@/my/file/path/from/variable/tshootinginfo.txt" ${jira_subtask}/attachments
```

I have tried multiple different escapes known to me in a bash, but no much progress. 
The escape tried:

```
location_var="/my/file/path/from/variable/tshootinginfo.txt"

-F "file=\"@$location_var\""
-F "file=@\"$location_var\""
-F "file=@\'$location_var\'"
-F "file=@\${location_var}"
```

Comment: Kindly do post whatever you have tried to escape(which you mentioned in your question) with code tags and let us know then.

Comment: You're using too many quotes and escapes. Try `-F "file=@${location_var}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument after `-F file=@...` is simply a string.

```
curl -s -k -D- -u "${user}:${password}" \
    -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" \
    -F "file=@$my_location_var" \
    "${jira_subtask}/attachments"
```

You can put braces around the variable name if you like, but it is not necessary in any of these cases. Take care to [quote your variables properly,](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642) though.